# switch statement creating infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, scanf

I am writing a piece of code and in one part of my code I am using a switch statement in C language. if I press n it exits correctly if I press y it will infinite loop the default statement until I press control c. what am I doing wrong here. been changing the while statement but can't find the right one.

```
int main()
{
    char ans;
    printf("DO you want to continue?");
    scanf("%c", &ans);
    do
    {
      switch(ans)
      {
            case 'y':
                some stuff...
                   printf("DO you want to continue?");
                   scanf("%c", &ans);
                   break;
            case'n':
                  printf("BYE");
                  break;
            default:
                 printf("error, you must enter y or n");
                 continue;
       }
   }
   while (ans!='n');
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks like C to me ...

Comment: Wouldn't you like to let the user try again to enter a character in the event that s/he doesn't enter "y" or "n" and you print an error msg?

Answer (score 1):

When you press enter, the linefeed character `\n` is added to the input stream. Your code does not anticipate this, because `switch(ans)` only handles `y`, `n` or “everything else” (which includes the linefeed character).

To fix this, allow `scanf` to ignore any preceding whitespace by changing your format string to `" %c"` instead, e.g.

```
scanf(" %c", &ans);
//     ^ space character inserted here
```

I think it would make more sense to move the `scanf` call to inside the loop, like this:

```
int main()
{
    char ans;

    do
    {
        printf("DO you want to continue?");
        if (scanf(" %c", &ans) != 1)
            break;

        switch(ans)
        {
            case 'y':
                //  some stuff...
                break;
            case 'n':
                printf("BYE");
                break;
            default:
                printf("error, you must enter y or n");
                continue;
        }
    }
    while (ans!='n');
}
```

Don't forget to always check the result of `scanf()`. It will return the number of items successfully scanned (in your case, you want it to return 1). If it returns 0 or a negative number, then another problem has occurred.

Comment: i just figured that out as i check this post! lol thank you though.